# How to attach files to emails on iPhone running iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, ios

Here is my dilemma/situation:

1. I download a PDF (or any other type) file from somewhere (i.e Safari, Email, Google Drive, etc.) into an application that can open it (i.e. Documents by Readdle)
2. I make some adjustments/edit the file using the app (i.e Documents by Readdle).
3. I go to the Email app and open an email that I want to reply to. I type up my message.
4. **The problem**: Now I want to attach that file I just edited in the app (i.e. Documents by Readdle) into this email reply that I am typing up.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Documents by Readdle lets you send any arbitrary file over email. Select the file in Documents, tap Actions, then Mail to. This composes a new email with the file attached.

Upgrade to iOS 9 and you can attach arbitrary files from Apple's mail client. Documents can export files to iCloud drive for easy attachment or you can just save the file to iCloud drive from the get go and skip the Documents unless it ads value to your workflow.

Comment: @bmike Thanks for the update! I feel like I need to go through all my old answers and update them for new OS X/iOS, one day…!

Answer (score 2):

This feature is added in iOS9, although it will be up to individual apps to implement the ability to share each type of document (and some, like webarchive, are not particularly well-documented)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Simply said. It's the developers job to incorporate core functionality like this. With an app that saves files to your device, it's only allowed to save files to the apps bundle folder on the device and no where else. So that greatly limits its functionally. Apple is slowly introducing cross-application features like sharing files etc but again it's still up to the developer to update their apps to be compatible. Readdle offers in app email using apples mail composer view controller however, if your goal is to reply to a specific email using mail and attach a file just like a desktop it's not possible at this time. Just take Apple for example, they don't have an attachment button either to support iWork's documents or their own files. A current workaround is just to just tap and hold to copy the file (if your app allows this) and paste it into mail like you have to do for pictures, other than that you will have to create a new email thread by using the in-app email feature.

Answer (score 0):

At this point of time, you could try the [CloudMagic Email](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloudmagic-email/id721677994?mt=8) app. The app allows you to attach documents via the Documents app by Readdle.

Answer (score 0):

Install Google's Gmail or another email app and use it for email. Attach files easily by viewing the file share icon and add the new email app to the apps that can share files (or do this under settings separately.) Select the email app as the share tool and hit send.

Some email apps may let you attach files like you do on your desktop with no need for using share.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use myMail app from the AppStore

Comment: Hi Sharif, Welcome to Ask Different, please elaborate your answer as to why and how to use the application mentioned by you.